# Why I don't need to escape ASCII characters like \037 in String declaration?

Tags: java

I know "" is the escape character in Java. So my understanding is that whenever i declare a string which contain special characters I need to escape it by "". for eg:

```
String backSlash = "\\";
```

I have to create a String for ascii character \037 and apparently it seems that I don't need to escape it with "".

```
String delimiter = "\037"; // enough                                   
String delimiter = "\\037"; // not needed and wrong
```

Why is that?

Comment: The point of escaping a backslash is to say "I don't want the special meaning of backslash; I want an actual backslash". If you want to represent the character `\037` then you _do_ want the special meaning of backslash, so escaping it is exactly not what you want.

Comment: So the ASCII code \037 is not literal \037 ? it is there to escape 0 ?

Comment: It is there to escape 037 into being octal, instead of "0" "3" "7".

Comment: so the \ gives the whole string the octal meaning. Thanks EJP, i accidentally removed my upvote, sorry for that...

Comment: @Despicableme No, it causes the next character to be interpreted as a literal zero, which is lexically is the start of an octal literal. When the octal literal is consumed the remainder of the string continues to be processed.

Answer (score 3):

> My understanding is that whenever I declare a string which contain special characters I need to escape it by `"\"`

Your understanding is incomplete: backslash `\` inside Java string literals can introduce an escape sequence of [one of three types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6):

- **Special character escape** - this includes `\b`, `\t`, `\n`, `\f`, `\r`, `\'`, `\"`, and `\\`
- **Unicode escape** - A sequence that starts with `\u` and has up to four hexadecimal digits
- **Octal escape** - A sequence that starts with `\` and has an octal number between 0 and 377<sub>8</sub> starting with 0

Your example has the sequence of the third kind (octal).

Answer (score 1):

You're writing an [octal number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1):

> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit 0 followed by one or more of the ASCII digits 0 through 7 interspersed with underscores, and can represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.

If written "037", it'll later be iterpreted as "0" "3" "7".

Comment: It will be interpreted as the three characters "0" "3" "7" if you omit the backslash.

Comment: @EJP True, I had a different scenario for the hidden code in my mind :) Corrected.

Comment: @Despicableme Don't post clickbait here, but have you considered the possibility that it is the same question with the same answer?